# Impact of Satellite Movement on Signal Processing Between Tx and Rx:

Tags: communication-satellite, movement

I am researching how the movement of satellites affects signal processing between a transmitter (Tx) and receiver (Rx). Satellites can function as either transmitters or receivers.

The movement will alter the communication link between the satellite and user devices. From my physics course, I am familiar with the Doppler effect, which causes spectrum shifts. What other effects might occur? Could it impact resource allocation algorithms or power allocation? How about demodulation, modulation, decoding, and encoding?

To be honest, I am particularly interested in understanding whether satellite movement affects the placement of network functions (RAN architecture). However, I am unsure if this is the right place to pose this question.

Comment: This is not specific to satellites, by the way. WiFi and cellular also have "speed limits". For example, the original 1990s GSM could not be used on high-speed trains and jet airplanes because the relative velocity between handset and base station was too high.

Comment: What kind of satellites are you considering? Geo-synchronous (which usually trace a figure-8 in the sky) or LEO (which whizz past)? What about the users, are they at fixed ground positions, slow moving, fast moving? You could check the [MH370 satellite communications analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370_satellite_communications) for quite a few pointers on relevant subject in one of those combinations (geosynchronous, fast moving). Ground-satellite only or inter-satellite?